# Using activity level dependencies in fragments with dagger2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a project structure like this:

```
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, 
ActivityBinderModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApplication> 
{...}
```

I have a bunch of app level dependencies defined in `AppModule`

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBinderModule {

@ActivityScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {MainActivityModule.class, FragmentBinderModule.class})
abstract MainActivity bindMainActivity();
}
```

I have some activity level dependencies defined in `MainActivityModule`, e.g. the `FragmentManager`

```
@Module
public abstract class FragmentBinderModule {

@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MainPageModule.class)
@FragmentScope
abstract MainPageFragment provideMainPageFragment();
}
```

I have the `MainPageFragment` specific dependencies defined in `MainPageModule`, like `DialogFactory` (scoped with `@FragmentScope`), which needs a `FragmentManager`

I would like to use the `FragmentManager` instance provided by `MainActivityModule` in `DialogFactory`, but I got the error:

`FragmentManager cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

When I add a provider for the `FragmentManager` in `MainPageModule`, I get this error:

`FragmentManager is bound multiple times: MainActivityModule and MainPageModule`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `FragmentManager` the `Android FragmentManager` or some class of yours ?

Comment: the Android one, `SupportFragmentManager`

Comment: why do you need dagger to provide that for you?

Comment: So I can just inject it to all the classes needing it, but my question is a bit bigger then that, I could have asked it more generally: `How can I inject Activity level dependencies into Fragment level objects?`, this was just the example triggering it

Comment: in your case you have to different modules providing the same dependency (`FragmentManager`). To circumvent the error you can use the `@Named` annotation. In the specific case, I don't see the reason to inject something, the system provides already.

Comment: At first I was only providing `FragmentManager` from the `MainActivityModule`, I even tried it with the `@Named` annotation, I still got `FragmentManager cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`. But when I'm adding it to the `MainPageModule` (with the `@Named` annotation), I got the error above, that I'm providing it in two places. It looks like dagger only sees the `Provides` in the `MainActivityModule` when there is another provider in the `MainPageModule`

Comment: As for providing the `FragmentManager`, I think it's much better then injecting e.g. the `Fragment` instance and getting the `FragmentManager` from that. I can't just get the `FragmentManager` in a standalone class like `DialogFactory`

Comment: I wonder if you actually *can* make the Fragment injector be a subcomponent of the subcomponent generated by `@ContributesAndroidInjector` for the Activity...

Comment: Yeah me too... Maybe you can't since the fragment can be added to more then one activities